# Android notification channels in Oreo required?

Tags: facebook, android-notifications, android-8.0-oreo

We are forced to use notification channels in Oreo to allow notifications to work in our code as far as I'm aware, but I have noticed that several big apps like Facebook, Instagram and KIK don't have channels in the system settings activity.

It appears to only have; 
turn notifications on or off as a whole,
allow notification dot,
allow sound and
Interrupts in priority only

My Question is how is this possible?
Can you create channels once off? or on the fly? so they don't appear in the users settings app

It seems they can still control the setting of led color and vibration in the app without the channel, and where can I learn to do this?

My reasoning is, it would be silly to have your own settings for notifications in your app allowing a user to change and have those overridden when installed on oreo phones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notification will not be posted in Android 8.0 devices, if we upgraded the target SDK version to 26.We need to include notification channels in order to post notification.

Link from developer.android.com which describes Notification channel
[click here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#ManageChannels)

The link clearly says that, When you target Android 8.0 (API level 26), you must implement one or more notification channels to display notifications to your users. If you don't target Android 8.0 (API level 26) but your app is used on devices running Android 8.0 (API level 26), your app behaves the same as it would on devices running Android 7.1 (API level 25) or lower.

As you mentioned Facebook, Instagram may not have updated their target SDK to 26  so that why it appears so.If a app is updated their target SDK to 26 then there will be a Categories option to display the channel names.

[image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRW7E.png)

If you already have a notification settings in your app,you can just group all your notification under a single channel as "Default". This is just my suggestion :)

Comment: Thank you @Suthakar that makes complete sense to me, thanks for your time.